# How can I make a class recognize that an interface found in a separate file exists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, interface, dotnetnuke

I've made an interface called `ApprovalEvent` in a separate file with the namespace `myproject`... I've also made a class called `PurchaseOrder`... it's also in the same namespace, just in a separate file. Whenever I try to make `PurchaseOrder` implement `ApprovalEvent` it always says that `ApprovalEvent is undefined`...

How can I make the class recognize that the interface exists but is in a different file?

**Here's some code:**

File #1

```
Namespace myproject
    Public Interface ApprovalEvent
        Function getDetails() As String
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

File #2

```
Namespace myproject
    Partial Class PurchaseOrder 
        Inherits Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase 
        Implements ApprovalEvent

        Function getDetails() As String Implements ApprovalEvent.getDetails
            return "details"
        End FUnction
    End Class  
End Namespace
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: There should be no issue with this as you describe it. Maybe you could get some better help if you posted code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate project too?  Does the one project include the other as a reference if so?  That shouldn't be a problem from what I can see.  It works no problem.  Try temporarily including the interface in the same file too, see if that helps.

Comment: No, same project. It does work if I put it in the same file... just can't find it in the other file. The other file is in the same directory as well...

Comment: Is the file included in the project (i. e. right click it and choose Include in Project)?  Does the file with the interface have a Namespace statement in it?  If you could show some code it would be helpful.

Comment: 1 sec, I'll see if I can grab some. Yes it is included in the project

Comment: What type of project is this?  Is it a web site or web application project?  If so, where are the files located in the project?

Comment: web site. The files are within a folder called Approval under DesktopModules. I just added some code, hopefully that'll help...

Comment: In web site project, all code files need to be in the App_Code folder that are not code-behind page files.  So your interface would and if this class isn't a code-behind file, both would need to be in app_code.  Even better would be to have any code files in a separate project, then reference that project in the web site.

Comment: No problem.  Could you mark the thread as the answer then?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the huge delay on marking it answered. Thanks again for the help.